# How to reuse react components in different html pages

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

im having problems with re-using react components in two different html pages

heres the structure of my app

```
react app
    |-- webpack.config
    |-- package
    `-- src
        |-- index.js
        |-- index.html
        |-- home.html
        `-- components
            |-- Main.js
            |-- Sector.js
            |-- Homepage.js
```

okay in webpack.config i have
        this

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',


entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:' + defaultSettings.port,
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'

  ],

    output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/../dist/assets'),
    filename: 'app.js',
  },


  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' }
    ]
  }
}
```

in index.js

```
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Appd from './components/Main';
import Sector from './components/sector';
import Homepagesector from './components/Homepagesector';

ReactDOM.render(<Appd />, document.getElementById('app'));
ReactDOM.render(<Sector />, document.getElementById('sector'));  
ReactDOM.render(<Homepagesector />, document.getElementById('homepage'));
```

in index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html >

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>zilla</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
</head>

  <!-- REQUIRED 3/3 - the image crop directive -->


   <body >
      <header>
         <div id="app"></div>
      </header>

      <script src="appcontroller.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = parent.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__</script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/app.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resample.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="avatar.js"></script>
</body>      
</html>
```

in home.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>   
<body >
<header>
  <div id="homepage"></div>
</header>
   <script src="appcontroller.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = parent.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__</script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/app.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="resample.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="avatar.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="avatar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In components folder 
Main.js

```
require('styles/App.css');

import React from 'react';

let yeomanImage = require('../images/zilla.png');

class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          <img src={yeomanImage} alt="Yeoman Generator" /> 
          <h1 className="title"></h1>  
          <li>
             <a href="index2.html"  className="a7" >Signin</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="index.html" className="a7" >Register</a>
          </li>         
       </div>

In components folder
```

Sector.js

```
require('styles/sector.css');

import React from 'react';

let yeomanImage = require('../images/dealzilla.png');

let yeomanImaged = require('../images/256.jpg');

class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         data: 'Initial data...'
      }

      this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);

   };

   updateState(e) {
      this.setState({data: e.target.value});
   }
  render() {


    return (
       <div className="page-wrap">
          <h1>not registered?register for free</h1>
          <div className="profile">
             <div className="profile-avatar-wrap">
               <img src={yeomanImaged} alt="Yeoman Generator" id="profile-avatar" alt="Image for Profile"/>
             </div>
             <div className="location">upload avatar</div>              
          </div>
          <h3>You could do this with a file input too...</h3>
       <div>
          <input type = "text" value = {this.state.data} 
               onChange = {this.updateState} />
          <h4>{this.state.data}</h4>
       </div>
    </div>
```

In components folder

homepage.js

```
import React from 'react';

let yeomanImage = require('../images/dealzilla.png');

class AppedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          <img src={yeomanImage} alt="Yeoman Generator" /> 
          <h1 className="title">dealzilla</h1> 
          <li>
             <a href="index2.html"  className="a7" >Search</a>
             <a href="index2.html"  className="a7" >Search</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="index.html" className="a7" >Register</a>
          </li>    
       </div>
   );
  }
}

AppedComponent.defaultProps = {
};

export default AppedComponent;
```

The problem is that I am not able to use homepage.js component
in my home.html page
it doesnt appear at all
however my Main.js component is able to appear

Im still a beginner in react, I've looked around for answers and didnt find any on this regard
any help would be appreciated 
thank you in advance
best regards

Comment: I am curious as to why all your components have the same name? This will most likely cause you problem when trying to use multiple components in the same page. Have you tried a different naming for your components?

Comment: hi Sandwichz  i changed the name and i still get the same results.it seems to me as if reactlibrary isnt consistent on my part,becouse when changing the names of my components ,the components dont appear anymore on the html pages.only one component works and thats the Main.js one.

Answer (score 0):

heres what i ended up using maybe it will help someone out there who also got stuck
https://ui-router.github.io/react/

its a great tool to use with react coming from angular